# Inheritance issue

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

this may be an amateur question, but here it goes. I have three clases:

DrawableObject:

```
class DrawableObject
{
private:

    int x;
    //...
public:
    int getX();
        //...
}
```

FormElement which inheirts from DrawableObject:

```
class FormElement : public DrawableObject
```

FormElement has a method called wasPushed:

```
bool FormElement::wasPushed(SDL_Event event)
{
bool wasPushed =
        (
            ( event.motion.x >= getX()) //Inherited getX()
            && // Blah blah...
        ) ? true : false;

return wasPushed;
}
```

Finally, TextField, which inheirts from FormElement:

```
class TextField : public DrawableObject
```

I also have a class, named Form:

```
class Form {

public:

    list<FormElement*> getFormElements();
    void generateForm();

private:

    list<FormElement*> formElements;
}
```

Form adds some TextFields to its list, in its generateForm() method:

```
void Form::generateForm() {

TextField *aTextField = new TextField(10, 10, 120);
    this->formElements.push_back(aTextField);
}
```

Later, it tries to iterate it:

```
for(list<FormElement*>::iterator it = getFormElements().begin()
    ; it != getFormElements().end()
    ; ++it)
        {
          if ( (*it)->wasPushed(theEvent) )
            { //Etc.
```

Well, the program exits, when it tries to access getX() from wasPushed method.

Could anyone please tell me why? What am I defining wrong?

I thank you very much.
Martín.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the list by value:

```
list<FormElement*> getFormElements();
```

it should be by reference:

```
list<FormElement*> &getFormElements();
```

When you return by value, you are getting a temporary copy of the list.

So in this code:

```
for(list<FormElement*>::iterator it = getFormElements().begin()
    ; it != getFormElements().end()
```

Your begin and end iterators are pointing to two different copies of the list.  Also, those temporary copies will be destroyed before you ever have a chance to iterate over them.

You could also use the formElements member directly:

```
for(list<FormElement*>::iterator it = formElements.begin()
    ; it != formElements.end()
    ; ++it)
```

Comment: I love you so much, sir! That was it! Thank you VERY much!

Comment: @iL_Marto - Don't just love Vaughn. Accept the answer!

Comment: Haha. You are right, David Hammen. I am new to this. Sorry. Totally accepted.

Comment: Also, TextField should inherit from FormElement, not DrawableObject.

Comment: You are totally right, irobot. A mistake of mine when typing. As you said, it actually inherits from FormElement.